# How to connect selenium node to hub on MAC?

Tags: macos, safari, selenium-grid, safari-extension

I have selenium hub running on windows machine. Now I want to do

Step 1: setup of selenium node on MAC machine (using JSON file),

Step 2: connect the node to hub and

Step 3: execute suite on safari.

Please guide me through all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

- Setup node on a MAC machine and connect to hub.

Its similar to how you would setup the Hub. You download the Selenium standalone jar from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and then start the node using `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register` [ replace `localhost` with the IP address of the machine where your Hub is running and replace `4444` with the port number on which your hub is listening to.

- Execute suite on safari

I am not quite sure how much is Safari automation reliable. You can refer to the below links for more information.

- [Safari Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver)
- [Safari Driver Internals](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver-Internals)